# How to convert string to JSON in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, json, django, combobox

I used Django framework to implement a web project. I take a set of data objects from a MongoDB database and set them to a combobox. I have two comboboxes and changing the value in the first one changes the value in the second one.

This is my view HTML file code.

```
 <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-controls">
              <label>By Product Code  </label>
               <select name="productCode" id="onecb">
                   <option></option>
                 {% for entry in product_code %}
                       <option value="{{ entry.code }}">{{ entry.product_name }}</option>
                  {% endfor %}

             </select>
            </div>
         </div>

         <!--<div class="form-group">
            <label>By Product Code </label>
            <input  type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Product Code" name="productCode" maxlength="5" max="1000">
         </div> -->

         <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-controls">
              <label>By Batch Code   </label>
               <select name="batchCode" id="twocb">
                 <option></option>
                 {% for entry in batch %}
                       <option value="{{ entry }}">{{ entry.batch_code }}</option>
                  {% endfor %}
             </select>
            </div>
         </div>
```

this is my JavaScript code.

```
<script>
    var first = document.getElementById('onecb'), second = document.getElementById('twocb');



    var ddlArray= new Array();
    for(i = 0; i < second.options.length; i++) {
        ddlArray[i] = second.options[i].value;

        //var obj = JSON.parse(ddlArray[i]);
        console.log(ddlArray[i]);
    }


   first.onchange = function (e) {
       var val = e.target.value;
       empty(second);

       for (i = 0; i < ddlArray.length; i++) {
           //if(ddlArray[i] == val){
                addOption(ddlArray[i], second);
           ///}


       }
   };

    function empty(select) {
      select.innerHTML = '';
    }

    function addOption(val, select) {
      var option = document.createElement('option');
      option.value = val;
      option.innerHTML = val;
      select.appendChild(option);
    }


</script>
```

The console output:

```
{'batch_code': 'B001', 'created_date': datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 16, 12, 57, 11, 394000), '_id': ObjectId('569a3e27f125be38311fe15a'), 'key_quntity': 12, 'product_code': 0}
{'batch_code': 'B002', 'created_date': datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 16, 12, 58, 21, 183000), '_id': ObjectId('569a3e6df125be38311fe167'), 'key_quntity': 21, 'product_code': 2}
```

but when I uncomment this line

```
//var obj = JSON.parse(ddlArray[i]);
```

it gives this error

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

----------------what i want to do---------------------------------

I want that when I select a product code from the first combo-box, only relative Batch Codes are loaded to the second combo-box.

eg.: I select product code two(2) in the first combo-box, then 'B002' is loaded to the second combo-box.

-------------------after edit----------------------------------------

according to a reply, I get only product id and batch code like this:

```
{'product_code': 0, 'batch_code': 'B001'} 
{'product_code': 2, 'batch_code': 'B002'} 
{'product_code': 1, 'batch_code': 'B089'}
```

but I still get the same error.

Comment: That's not valid JSON.

Comment: @Pointy  , i get data from mongoDB database , i want to iterate this obect and take 'product code ' and 'Batch Code ' separately.

Comment: Make ObjectId and datetime a string via calling their respective toString() method.

Comment: I change '{'product_code': 0, 'batch_code': 'B001'} 
{'product_code': 2, 'batch_code': 'B002'} 
{'product_code': 1, 'batch_code': 'B089'} 'but still same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use the RegExp for parsing

```
var str = "{'batch_code': 'ikk', 'created_date': datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 16, 12, 57, 11, 394000), '_id': ObjectId('569a3e27f125be38311fe15a'),     'key_quntity': 12, 'product_code': 0}";
var reg1 = /(?:\'product_code\'\:)\s+(\w+)/;
var reg2 = /(?:\'batch_code\'\:\s+\')(\w+)/;
var product_code = reg1.exec(str)[1];//ikk
var batch_code = reg2.exec(str)[1];  //0
```

Comment: @Stanisalv Thank you .I want take only B001 and 0 . I don't want take batch_code and product_code word. plz ,expect some answer.

Comment: ,sorry when execute this sting , {'batch_code': 'ikk', 'product_code': 3}  , pass this error , TypeError: reg2.exec(...) is null  , can you help me. ?

Comment: @THank you ,sir ,now every thing is ok.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: For Javascript, single quote and double quote are both valid for quoting a string. eg: both "name" and 'name' are valid; 
For JSON, however, only double quote is valid. eg. "name" is valid. 'name' is not valid. So:

```
JSON.parse({'product_code': 0, 'batch_code': 'B001'})
```

It will fail: because {'product_code': 0, 'batch_code': 'B001'} is not a string;

```
JSON.parse("{'product_code': 0, 'batch_code': 'B001'}")
```

It will also fail because the property name is single-quoted (NOT JSON standard)

```
JSON.parse("{\"product_code\": 0, \"batch_code\": \"B001\"}")
```

It will work

```
JSON.parse('{"product_code": 0, "batch_code": "B001"}')
```

It will also work, alternatively.